# Java EE, EJB, JPA: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jpa, ejb, cdi

I creating a small online store using Java EE 8, JSF, and JPA. I am getting a null pointer exception whenever the line `Item item1 = itemDAO.findById(1);` is called in my code (in `ShoppingCartPresenter.class`). The exception appears whenever I try to load the `showcart.xhtml` JSF file. When I am trying to debug my program, I see that the `itemDAO` is not null. I also notice that the `findById()` method is never entered. I suspect it is a problem with the injection, but I am really not sure because the exception message really doesn't help me finding the source of the problem.

Could you please help me spot where is null pointer exception is occuring?

Exception Stack:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke private void com.javaproject.musicbox.managedbeans.storefront.ShoppingCartPresenter.init() on com.javaproject.musicbox.managedbeans.storefront.ShoppingCartPresenter@41230ce7
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:700)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:337)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1673)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1673)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:492)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:732)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:446)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2635)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2028)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy332.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.javaproject.musicbox.daos.__EJB31_Generated__ItemDAO__Intf____Bean__.findById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at com.javaproject.musicbox.daos.ItemDAO$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.javaproject.musicbox.managedbeans.storefront.ShoppingCartPresenter.init(ShoppingCartPresenter.java:32)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:715)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:219)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:442)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:525)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:99)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:713)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1738)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:467)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.<init>(CallbackInvocationContext.java:119)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.<init>(CallbackInvocationContext.java:134)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:399)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:380)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2071)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIAroundConstructCallback.aroundConstruct(JCDIAroundConstructCallback.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallback(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer._createJCDIInjectionContext(BaseContainer.java:1768)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1719)
    ... 90 more
```

ShoppingCartPresenter.class:

```
package com.javaproject.musicbox.managedbeans.storefront;

import com.javaproject.musicbox.daos.ItemDAO;
import com.javaproject.musicbox.daos.ShoppingCartDAO;
import com.javaproject.musicbox.entities.Item;
import com.javaproject.musicbox.entities.ShoppingCart;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ShoppingCartPresenter implements Serializable {
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    @Inject private ShoppingCartDAO shoppingCartDAO;
    @Inject private ItemDAO itemDAO;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // Since we don't have logged in users yet, every time a session is created
        // a new cart is created for this session. Later a check will be needed to
        // verify if the user is logged and load his cart if he is logged in
        shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

        Item item1 = itemDAO.findById(1);
        Item item2 = itemDAO.findById(2);
        Item item3 = itemDAO.findById(3);

        shoppingCart.addItem(item1);
        shoppingCart.addItem(item2);
        shoppingCart.addItem(item3);
    }

    /**
     * This addItemToCart() method adds an item to the cart
     *
     * @param itemId The id of the item to add
     */
    public void addItemToCart(int itemId) {
        // Finding the item with the itemId that was passed to the method
        Item itemAdded = itemDAO.findById(itemId);

        shoppingCart.addItem(itemAdded);
    }

    /**
     * This removeItemFromCart() method removes an item from the cart
     *
     * @param itemId The id of the item to remove
     */
    public void removeItemFromCart(int itemId) {
        Item itemToRemove = itemDAO.findById(itemId);

        shoppingCart.removeItem(itemToRemove);
    }

    /**
     * The isCartEmpty() method verifies if the cart is empty
     *
     * @return True if the shopping cart is true
     */
    public boolean isCartEmpty() {
        return shoppingCart.getItems().size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the total price of the cart
     *
     * TODO Add taxes
     *
     * @return The total price of the cart
     */
    public double calculateTotal() {
        double total = 0;

        for (Item item: shoppingCart.getItems()) {
            total += item.getListPrice();
        }

        return total;
    }



    public ShoppingCart getShoppingCart() {
        return shoppingCart;
    }
}
```

AbstractDAO.class:

```
package com.javaproject.musicbox.daos;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The AbstractDAO contains the common functionality for almost all the DAOs,
 * for example, create(), findById(), update(), delete() ...
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the Entity
 */
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bookspu")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractDAO(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an entity (i.e. takes an entity object and persists it)
     *
     * @param entity The entity to create
     * @return The same entity that was created
     */
    public T create(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    /**
     * Finds an entity by id
     *
     * @param id The id of the entity to find
     * @return The entity that has the id that was searched
     */
    public T findById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an entity
     *
     * @param entity The entity to update
     * @return The same entity that was updated
     */
    public T update(T entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an entity from the database
     *
     * @param entity The entity to remove
     */
    public void delete(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entity));
    }



}
```

ItemDAO.class

```
package com.javaproject.musicbox.daos;


import com.javaproject.musicbox.entities.Item;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * The ItemDAO is a data access class that is responsible for the
 * Item Entity
 */
@Stateless
public class ItemDAO extends AbstractDAO<Item> implements Serializable {
    ItemDAO () {
        super(Item.class);
    }
}
```

ShoppingCart.class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.javaproject.musicbox.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The Shopping Cart entity
 *
 * @author Yanik
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "shopping_cart")
public class ShoppingCart implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "shopping_cart_id")
    private int shoppingCartId;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "shopping_cart_item",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "shopping_cart_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Item> items;

    public int getShoppingCartId() {
        return shoppingCartId;
    }

    public void setShoppingCartId(int shoppingCartId) {
        this.shoppingCartId = shoppingCartId;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ShoppingCart that = (ShoppingCart) o;
        return Objects.equals(shoppingCartId, that.shoppingCartId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(shoppingCartId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShoppingCart{" +
                "shoppingCartId=" + shoppingCartId +
                ", items=" + items +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Item.class

```
package com.javaproject.musicbox.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * The Item entity
 *
 * @author Yanik
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private int itemId;

    @Column(name = "list_price")
    private double listPrice;

    @Column(name = "cost_price")
    private double costPrice;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "picture_path")
    private String picturePath;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_added")
    private Date dateAdded;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_removed")
    private Date dateRemoved;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    private List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCarts;

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public double getListPrice() {
        return listPrice;
    }

    public void setListPrice(double listPrice) {
        this.listPrice = listPrice;
    }

    public double getCostPrice() {
        return costPrice;
    }

    public void setCostPrice(double costPrice) {
        this.costPrice = costPrice;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath;
    }

    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }

    public Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public Date getDateRemoved() {
        return dateRemoved;
    }

    public void setDateRemoved(Date dateRemoved) {
        this.dateRemoved = dateRemoved;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return itemId == item.itemId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(itemId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "itemId=" + itemId +
                ", listPrice=" + listPrice +
                ", costPrice=" + costPrice +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", picturePath='" + picturePath + '\'' +
                ", dateAdded=" + dateAdded +
                ", dateRemoved=" + dateRemoved +
                ", shoppingCarts=" + shoppingCarts +
                '}';
    }
}
```

showcart.xhtml (JSF file):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="/templates/storefrontTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form rendered="#{!shoppingCartPresenter.cartEmpty}">
            <h:dataTable value="#{shoppingCartPresenter.shoppingCart.items}" var="item" styleClass="table">

                <!-- ITEM PICTURE -->
                <h:column>
                    <h:graphicImage url="/resources/images/music.png" alt="Item"/>
                </h:column>

                <!-- ITEM NAME -->
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                </h:column>

                <!-- ITEM PRICE -->
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.listPrice}"/> $
                </h:column>

                <!-- REMOVE FROM CART BUTTON -->
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{shoppingCartPresenter.removeItemFromCart(item.itemId)}"
                                   styleClass="remove-from-cart"
                                   value="Remove">
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

            <br/>


            <!-- TOTAL PRICE -->
            <div>
                Total $
                <h:outputText value="#{shoppingCartPresenter.calculateTotal}"/>
            </div>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: The error/cause is in the stacktrace. The stateless ejb cannot be created and hence not injected. Look at its constructor

Comment: @Kukeltje I can't find what is wrong with it, am I missing something?

Comment: No idea since the constructor calls a parent constructor which might fail. Debug, set breakpoints etc... All sort of basic development things.

Answer (score 1):

your base bean class is not a managed class, but is trying to inject the @PersistenceContext, which will always fail, resulting in an NPE.

i've seen this kind of "trick" before and it's unnecessary artistry.  keep your EJB simple, and lean.  BTW, you don't need a DAO layer if you're using EJB (except in certain exotic cases), because JPA is your DAO layer.  just streamline your ejb and make the calls directly from it.